# Should my helper method return a char or a string?

Tags: c#, string, char

XNA has a method, `Keyboard.GetState()`, which returns the state of the keyboard. You can poll to see if a particular key is pressed via the `Keys` enumeration, which "coincidentally" happens to be identical to the one that regular C# uses.

Anyways, I needed a way to convert the enumeration to readable letters, eg for typing into a custom textbox, so I made an extension method like so:

```
public static char ToChar(this Keys obj, bool shift, bool caps)
{
    switch (obj)
    {
        case (Keys.A): return (shift ^ caps) ? 'A' : 'a';
        case (Keys.B): return (shift ^ caps) ? 'B' : 'b';
        case (Keys.C): return (shift ^ caps) ? 'C' : 'c';

        ...

        case (Keys.OemOpenBrackets): return (!shift) ? '[' : '{';
        case (Keys.OemCloseBrackets): return (!shift) ? ']' : '}';
        case (Keys.OemPipe): return (!shift) ? '\\' : '|';
        case (Keys.OemSemicolon): return (!shift) ? ';' : ':';
        case (Keys.OemQuotes): return (!shift) ? '\'' : '"';
        case (Keys.OemComma): return (!shift) ? ',' : '<';
        case (Keys.OemPeriod): return (!shift) ? '.' : '>';
        case (Keys.OemQuestion): return (!shift) ? '/' : '?';

        ...

        default: return ' ';
    }
}
```

I'm not terribly concerned about the speed, since this will only be called as fast as the user can type and not within a tight loop. However, mashing the arrow keys or page up will result in  , a blank character being returned (as per default).

Would it actually make more sense to use a `char?`, returning null in the case that a non printable character is used? Or perhaps a `string`, so that I can return `String.Empty`?

Comment: Depending on how much information you might need, string might make more sense, or you could also create your own type which may contain context about the key that was pressed, and can likewise contain the key as one of its properties.

Comment: Try replacing `return ' '` with `return '\0'`, the [null character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: I was leaning towards char because it feels "lighter" and makes more sense in the context of keypresses. I do have the context as well, since this method is (potentially) called as a response to the key press event(s).

Comment: And @GrantWinney, that's exactly what I needed. If you post it as an answer, I'll give you a shiny green checkmark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this, which returns a space:

```
return ' ';
```

With this, where `\0` represents the [null character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
return '\0';
```

Since you're displaying these characters, hopefully now you won't get a long string of spaces.

Comment: I was using Console.WriteLine() to test the input as I typed it, and it seems to work fine for the most part. However, if I pass it the '\0' thing as above, it seems to not print any characters afterwards. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: I don't know. I can replicate it too. Apparently it isn't too happy with that input, but I'm not sure what's going on internally. I suppose as a workaround you could detect '\0' being returned and just not write it out to the console.